# setting up gufw via VNC

Tags: vnc, remmina, gufw

Suppose I am using `Remmina` to access `vnc4server` via this SSH tunnel:

ssh -L 5901:127.0.0.1:5901 user@remoteIp

Then I install `gufw`. It has an `on/off` switch. As soon as I switch it on there are no rules because I have not created any rules. Why doesn't port 22 immediately get blocked and my Remmina session fail?

Comment: You certainly can lock yourself out with any firewall so take care. My guess is that you are accepting established connections. Try to make a new one. If you need help you need to post your firewall (ufw) rules.

Comment: As I wrote, I had no rules but the Remmina session continued to work. Then I created a port 22 rule which I think is 2 rules because of IP version 4 and version 6. I deleted the IP version 6 rule and continued to use the session. Everything seems fine but I expected a failure.

Comment: Obviously your rules allow your conection. Again my guess is UFW allows established connections but blocks new connections. If you need help, post your rules and `sudo iptalbles -L` ufw is a front end for iptables and iptables differentiates NEW from ESTABLISHED connections. My guess is ufw DENY only blocks NEW connections. Did you try making a new connection ? At any rate , I can not answer if you do not post the requested information.